Unity 2D Manage Object Pool
I have an object Pool system so that, I don't keep instancing and deleting objects and just re-using them instead.
I want to change my scripts some how so there are alway "EnemyCount" shown on screen maybe with
However, I am trying to make it so that there are only so many of those object on screen defined by a count.
When an enemy hits a trigger I call the below
ObjectPoolManager.ReturnObjectToPool(gameObject);

EnemySpawner.cs

Contains reference to Count object (Controller.data.enemy1Info.count)
Right now it keeps spawning for a set interval.

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy1;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy2;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy3;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy4;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy5;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject spawnCircle;


    [SerializeField]
    private float enemy1Interval = 50f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float enemy2Interval = 100f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float enemy3Interval = 150f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float enemy4Interval = 250f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float enemy5Interval = 500f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy1Interval, enemy1));
        //StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy2Interval, enemy2));
        //StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy3Interval, enemy3));
        //StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy4Interval, enemy4));
        //StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy5Interval, enemy5));
        for (int i = 0; i < Controller.data.enemy1Info.count; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy1Interval, enemy1));
        }
    }

    public void IncreaseEnemySpawnCount() {
        StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(enemy1Interval, enemy1));
    }

    private IEnumerator spawnEnemy(float interval, GameObject enemy) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
        GameObject newEnemy = ObjectPoolManager.SpawnObject(enemy, getRandomSpawnPoint(), Quaternion.identity, ObjectPoolManager.PoolType.Gameobject);
        StartCoroutine(spawnEnemy(interval, enemy));
    }

    //Get Random Spawn point
    private Vector3 getRandomSpawnPoint() {
        int num = Random.Range(0, 11);
        return spawnCircle.transform.GetChild(num).gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class ObjectPoolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<PooledObjectInfo> ObjectPools = new List<PooledObjectInfo>();

    private GameObject _objectPoolEmptyHolder;

    private static GameObject _particleSystemEmpty;
    private static GameObject _gameObjectEmpty;

    public enum PoolType
    {
        ParticleSystem,
        Gameobject,
        None
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        SetupEmpties();
    }

    private void SetupEmpties()
    {
        _objectPoolEmptyHolder = new GameObject("Pooled Objects");

        _particleSystemEmpty = new GameObject("Particle Effects");
        _particleSystemEmpty.transform.SetParent(_objectPoolEmptyHolder.transform);

        _gameObjectEmpty = new GameObject("GameObjects");
        _gameObjectEmpty.transform.SetParent(_objectPoolEmptyHolder.transform);
    }

    public static GameObject SpawnObject(GameObject objectToSpawn, Vector3 spawnPosition, Quaternion spawnRotation, PoolType poolType = PoolType.None)
    {
        PooledObjectInfo pool = ObjectPools.Find(p => p.LookupString == objectToSpawn.name);

        // If the pool doesn't exist
        if (pool == null)
        {
            pool = new PooledObjectInfo() { LookupString = objectToSpawn.name };
            ObjectPools.Add(pool);
        }

        // Check if there are any inactive object in the pool
        GameObject spawnableObj = pool.InactiveObjects.FirstOrDefault();

        if (spawnableObj == null)
        {
            //Find the parent of the empty object
            GameObject parentObject = SetParentObject(poolType);

            // If there are no inactive object, create a new object to spawn
            spawnableObj = Instantiate(objectToSpawn, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);

            if (parentObject != null)
            {
                spawnableObj.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is an inactive object, re-use it
            spawnableObj.transform.position = spawnPosition;
            spawnableObj.transform.rotation = spawnRotation;
            pool.InactiveObjects.Remove(spawnableObj);
            spawnableObj.SetActive(true);
        }

        return spawnableObj;
    }

    public static void ReturnObjectToPool(GameObject obj)
    {
        // This is to remove (Clone) from object name
        string goName = obj.name.Substring(0, obj.name.Length - 7);

        PooledObjectInfo pool = ObjectPools.Find(p => p.LookupString == goName);

        if (pool == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Trying to release an object that is not pooled: " + obj.name);
        }
        else
        {
            obj.SetActive(false);
            pool.InactiveObjects.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    private static GameObject SetParentObject(PoolType poolType)
    {
        switch (poolType)
        {
            case PoolType.ParticleSystem:
                return _particleSystemEmpty;
            case PoolType.Gameobject:
                return _gameObjectEmpty;
            case PoolType.None:
                return null;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}


public class PooledObjectInfo
{
    public string LookupString;
    public List<GameObject> InactiveObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}

